# Laravel ping IP to check online or offline status

Tags: laravel, ip, ping

I am using Laravel v.6.11. I want to ping an IP:Port to check status if its online or offline. For that am using [**karlmonson/laravel-ping**](https://github.com/karlmonson/laravel-ping) package. Whenever i ping it returns wrong status sometimes server is ON and it returns false and vice versa.

**My Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Ping;

class PlexServerController extends Controller
{
    public function serverStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $ip = $request->ip;
        $port = $request->port;
        $health = Ping::check($ip.':'.$port);
        if($health == 200){
            return $json = json_encode(['status' => '1','health' => $health]);
        } else {
            return $json = json_encode(['status' => '2','health' => $health]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want someone to help me to get rid of this problem. I am also using [laravelcollective/remote](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/remote) to run SSH commands. Thats cool and it runs all commands. Anyone who can help me to solve out this problem of checking an IP if its online or offline and returns response with status code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay finally i got another solution after days of searching over google but forgot to post my answer as no one responded to it. You can follow following **curl** as its also built-in in **Laravel** and can be fast if you using Ubuntu/Linux based server. Below is am putting dummy **ip** and **port**

```
    $ip = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = '22';
    $url = $ip . ':' . $port;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $health = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($health) {
        $json = json_encode(['health' => $health, 'status' => '1']);
        return $json;
    } else {
        $json = json_encode(['health' => $health, 'status' => '0']);
        return $json;
    }
```